# Magento 2- Force Display Full Breadcrumb Path

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.7, breadcrumbs

I found recently that When I go from home to a product description page its breadcrumb not showing full path in Magento 2.1.8  just showing  home -> product . in magento 1.9 there is a fix but In magento 2.1.8 I am still unable to find any. is there any fix available ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix until now. Also Magento only links to single products (to avoid duplicate content and other issues).

See
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/21412/66934
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7967

Comment: plz check version

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is no fix in 2.x.